# Multiple variables in one for - Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, for-loop

Fellas! I'm creating my first independent project in Rails 3. This is mostly for practice. I've run in a problem.

The site gonna be about tarot predictions. In a form I ask for the deck and spread formation. In the controller I grab this and put in some variables. Than I have to list it out on the view.

The problem is: 
I have (for ex) 10 cards for 10 positions. I want to list one card description with one position description. In my solution I build an array for the position descriptions and put the cards in a for cycle. Than I shift out the positions from the array with every step of the for. 
In code:

```
<%  for cardnum in @cardnums
@cp = @card_positions.shift
@card = Card.find_by_id(cardnum)
%>
Writing out the data
<% end %>
```

However I think there are far more nice and clever solutions.

Is that possible to do the for cycle on two variables? Or any other nice solution?

Yours,
Kael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not exactly understand what you are trying to do, but

> cycle on two variables

If you mean to iterate on two arrays at once, [Array#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000260) can be helpful. You can do:

```
 a = [1,2,3]         # use card_position array
 b = %w{a b c}       # use cards array
 c = a.zip(b)        #=> [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]]

 # you can do
 c.each do |cp, card|
   # do something with card_position(cp) and card
 end
```

Comment: This array#zip looks nice! Is there any other ideas to solve a problem like this? (Rubish understood well my problem!)

Comment: one more side question! I cant figure out why do you use %w on the second line. What is that for?

Comment: that is just a short hand for writing string arrays without quotes.